# Mate: как задать позицию окнам при открытии

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Переместил главную панель в верхнею часть экрана

[image: скрин]

новые окна открываются под этой панелью, так что не возможно взять их за загловок и перетащить. Как можно это дело поправить, задать позицию окнам при открытии?

в качестве *de* используется [mate](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE).

Comment: для справки: с нажатой клавишей `alt` можно перетаскивать окна мышкой, «хватая» их в любом месте окна. если, конечно, в убунте-и-наследниках и в этом плане не поломали что-нибудь в x-сервере (как поломали в подсистеме xkb) // вообще-то к дистрибутиву mint ваш вопрос имеет гораздо меньшее отношение, чем к используемому вами wm. а вы его как раз и не назвали (ну или хотя бы de, если не знаете, какой именно wm в ней используется).

Comment: то что по умолчанию - MATE

Comment: если ничего не выйдет с позиционированием новых окон, можно как обходное средство использовать [автоскрытие панели](https://superuser.com/q/677917/454489).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение с помощью **CompizConfig Settings Manager**:

Перейти в **Window Management**, активировать **Place Windows**, выбрать **Placement Mode** значение **Centered**.